# Trouble with converting 5 star rating script to work with jQuery v1.3.2

Tags: jquery, rating

I'm having trouble converting this 5 star rating script that works perfect with jquery revision put out on Date: 2006-09-07 10:12:12 +0200 (Do, 07 Sep 2006) $* $Rev: 276 $

It's the addclass, removeclass, .extend functions that I think are the problem but I can't seem to successfully convert it to work with jquery v1.3.2?

Really need this to work asap.

Thanks for all your help... stackoverflow.com ROCKS!

Heres how you call it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#rate1').rating('postid', { maxvalue:5 });
});
</script>
<div id="rate1" class="rating">&nbsp;</div>
```

Heres the css:

```
.rating {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0em;
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
.rating:after {
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.cancel,
.star {
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cancel,
.cancel a {background: url(delete.gif) no-repeat 0 -25px;}

.star,
.star a {background: url(star.gif) no-repeat 0 0px;}

.cancel a,
.star a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 0 0px;
}

div.rating div.on a {
    background-position: 0 -25px;
}
div.rating div.hover a,
div.rating div a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}
```

And heres the rating script:

```
function postrating(i) {
    $("#rate_result").html(i);
}

function doSubmit() {
         var rating = $('#result').html();
         var reviewid = $('#reviewid').html();
         if(rating == '1') {
            alert('Are you kidding me!');
         }
         if(rating == '5') {
            alert('Thanks for the 5 star rating!');
         }
         alert(rating);
         alert(reviewid);
}

$.fn.rating = function(id, options) {
    if(id == null) return;
    var settings = {
        id       : id, // post changes to 
        maxvalue  : 5,   // max number of stars
        curvalue  : 0    // number of selected stars
    };
    if(options) {
       $.extend(settings, options);
    };
    $.extend(settings, {cancel: (settings.maxvalue > 1) ? true : false});
    var container = jQuery(this);
    $.extend(container, {
            averageRating: settings.curvalue,
            id: settings.id
        });
    for(var i= 0; i <= settings.maxvalue ; i++){
        var size = i
        if (i == 0) {
            if(settings.cancel == true){
                 var div = '';
                 container.append(div);
            }
        } 
        else {
             var div = '<div class="star"><a href="javscript:void(0)" onclick="javscript:postrating('+ i +');" title="'+i+' out of 5">'+i+'</a></div>';
             container.append(div);
        }
    }
    var stars = $(container).children('.star');
    stars
            .mouseover(function(){
                event.drain();
                event.fill(this);
            })
            .mouseout(function(){
                event.drain();
                event.reset();
            })
            .focus(function(){
                event.drain();
                event.fill(this)
            })
            .blur(function(){
                event.drain();
                event.reset();
            });
            stars.click(function(){
            if(settings.cancel == true) {
            settings.curvalue = stars.index(this) + 1;
            $.post(container.id, {
                "rating": $(this).children('a')[0].href.split('#')[1] 
            });
            return false;
            }
            else if(settings.maxvalue == 1) {
            settings.curvalue = (settings.curvalue == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            $(this).toggleClass('on');
            $.post(container.id, {
                "rating": $(this).children('a')[0].href.split('#')[1]
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    var event = {
        fill: function(el){ // fill to the current mouse position.
            var index = stars.index(el) + 1;
            stars
                .children('a').css('width', '100%').end()
                .lt(index).addClass('hover').end();
        },
        drain: function() { // drain all the stars.
            stars
                .filter('.on').removeClass('on').end()
                .filter('.hover').removeClass('hover').end();
        },
        reset: function(){ // Reset the stars to the default index.
            stars.lt(settings.curvalue).addClass('on').end();
        }
    }        
    event.reset();
    return(this);
}
```

Comment: Nope!  The 5 stars appear but when you highlight them... like if you highlight over the 4th star the previous four stars don't get highlighted and when you click.. like if you click on the 3rd star... the previous 3 stars don't get highlighted but I do get the value from the star when you click on it. 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Oh... the star you hover over does change from gray to yellow by the way!

Comment: I would start by making sure all your JSON objects are valid.  Most of the JSON objects you use are incorrect syntax.  You need double-quotes around the property names.  jQuery 1.4 got pickier about that, but it can't hurt to have it correct in 1.3.2, either.  I've run into IE6 issues when I use bad JSON objects in 1.3.2.

Comment: I added double-quotes around the property names... still getting the same issue?  I've checked the classes in both versions of jquery and they are different, addclass, removeclass, etc.  But not quite sure how to update the vars???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.lt()` is not a proper function. You are looking for the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector. Use a [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in order to use the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector.  Check your code where you have written `.lt(foo)` and instead write something like:

```
.filter(":lt(" + foo + ")")
```

Alternatively, you may want to look at [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)